# vim command mode always capitalize the first letter I entered

Tags: vim

Every time I enter the command mode and type `:`, the next letter I type always happen to be CAPITALIZED, this is really annoying because the vim does not understand what `:Wq` is or what `:Q` is, so I always have to delete what I typed and type again.

May I ask if there's a fix to this?

Edit: I haven't just encounter this problem on 1 computer, also I'm not just started using vim. This problem has been with me for at least a year with so many other computers (because I am a student who work in the computer lab).

At first I saw that it is because I typed too fast. Then I explicitly slow down. e.g. type `:` , take my hand off the keyboard, wait a second, then type `q`. Same effect. instead of the lovely `q` showing up. I got that ugly `Q`.

Comment: Get a better keyboard, and learn to type more precisely.

Comment: The Shift key in your keyboard seems to have a problem. Try a friend's keyboard and report back.

Comment: I haven't just encounter this problem on 1 computer, also I'm not just started using vim. This problem has been with me for at least a year with so many other computers (because I am a student who work in the computer lab).

Comment: Does this happen if you start Vim without any initialization files? (e.g.: `vim -u NONE -U NONE --noplugin -N`)

Comment: I have the same problem but it only happens if I type too quickly! If I wait a bit after typing : I get a nice lower case "w" but otherwise a big ugly "W"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps. An alternative is to hold down Shift and type zz.

Comment: this is helpful! may I ask if there's a write-not-quit version of it?

Comment: I don't think so. But you could use map. This example defines the F2 key to write the file. e.g. `:map <F2> :w!<CR>`

Comment: Mapping `W` to `w` isn't really a good idea.  I have the problem of not fully releasing shift after pressing `:` so I just created some user defined commands. For example: `:command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=file -range=% -bang W <line1>,<line2>write<bang> <args>`